# Create smaller products while guaranteeing uniqueness - Godel encoding

Tags: factoring, associativity, hash-function

I was reading about [Godel Numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) I was wondering if it is possible to create a unique number in a way (i.e. as a product), but with that the requirement the number does not grow at the rate of the numbers being multiplied.
Example for simplicity assume we map $d$ to $5$ and $g$  to $7$
The following sequence: $ddddddddddg = 5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot5\cdot7$
and the following sequence: $ggggggggggd$ = $7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot7\cdot5$
generates different products.
Is there a way to generate unique and different products but the resulting product is a lower number than the one the approach above produces?
I thought the following:
Use the unique characters and multiply their occurrences i.e.
$ddddddddddg => d10g1 => d\cdot10\cdot g\cdot1$
but due to associativity that is the same as:
$ggggggggggd => g10d1 => g\cdot10\cdot d\cdot1$

Is there some variation of Godel numbering that creates smaller products?

Comment: Any Godel numbering system can be "collapsed" as follows: supposing we have some map $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ (thinking of $X$ as the set of strings we're Godel-numbering), consider the new map $$Coll_f: x\mapsto\vert\{y\in X: f(y)<f(x)\}\vert.$$ For example, if $f(x)=2$ and there is no $y\in X$ such that $f(y)=0$ or $f(y)=1$, then $Coll_f(x)=0$. This eliminates the large gaps between Godel numbers. (Note that I consider $0$ a natural number; if you don't, replace "$f(y)<f(x)$" with "$f(y)\le f(x)$" in the definition of $Coll_f$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: does that guarantee uniqueness though? Also how is that mapping to $y$ created?

Comment: Yes, it guarantees uniqueness: if $f$ is injective (= different strings get different "codes") then so is $Coll_f$. As to your second question, I don't understand. The idea is that to figure out what $Coll_f(x)$ is, you look at how many elements of $X$ get sent, by $f$, to something smaller than $f(x)$. This number is what $Coll_f(x)$ is; there is no "mapping to $y$." For example: if $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $f: x\mapsto 2x$, then $f(17)=34$ but $Coll_f(17)=17$ (in fact $Coll_f$ is the identity).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I am a bit lost. The context of my question is software implementation and avoiding overflow. In the original case, I can just map directly to prime numbers and multiply. How would I calculate that $f(y) though? I didn't really get it. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Does $y$ depend on the original mapping?